# Perl Simple FIFO calculation

Tags: arrays, perl, fifo

I can not seem to get this FIFO calculation to work:

```
@base = (10,15,6,2);
@subtr = (2,4,6,2,2,5,7,2);

my $count = 0;
my $result;
my $prev;
foreach my $base1 (@base) {
    foreach my $subt (@subtr) {
        if ($count == 0) {
            $result = $base1 - $subt;
            print "$base1 - $subt = $result \n";
            if ($result > 0) {
                print "Still1 POS $result\n";
                $count = 1;
            } else {
                print "NEG1 now $result\n";
                $count = 1;
                next;
            }
        } else {
            $prev = $result;
            $result = $result - $subt;
            print "$prev - $subt = $result \n";
            if ($result > 0) {
                print "Still2 POS $result\n";
                next;
            } else {
                print "NEG2 now $result\n";
                $count = 1;
                next;
            }
        }
    }
    $count = 0;
}
```

I need it to subtract the numbers in @subtr from the 1st array @base, once the sum of the subt elements exceeds the 1st element of the @base array, for it to use the amount exceeded and subtract from second element of @base, etc until it is done. Once done, I need it to tell me which array from @base it finished on and how much is left from that array element( should be 1) and then how much is left total (should be 3).
Thank you in advance!
Paul

Answer (score 2):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 1.33 qw(sum any);  # 'any' was in List::MoreUtils pre-1.33

my @base = (10,15,6,2);
my @subt = (2,4,6,2,2,5,7,2);  # SUBTract from @base in a particular way ("FIFO")

# For testing other cases:
#my @subt = (2,4,6,2,2,5,7,2,5,5);  # @base runs out
#my @subt = (2,4,36,20);            # large @subt values, @base runs out
#my @subt = (2,4,21,2);             # large @subt values, @base remains
#my @subt = (2,4,6,2,2,5,7,2,3);    # @base runs out, @subt runs out

say "base: @base (total: ", sum(@base), ")";
say "sub:  @subt (total: ", sum (@subt), ")\n" if @subt;

my ($base_idx, $carryover) = (0, 0);

BASE_ELEM:
for my $bi (0..$#base) {
    $base[$bi] -= $carryover;

    # If still negative move to next @base element, to use carry-over on it
    if ($base[$bi] <= 0) {
        $carryover = abs($base[$bi]);
        say "\t\@base element #", $bi+1, " value $base[$bi] (-> 0); ",
            "carry over $carryover.";
        $base[$bi] = 0;
        next BASE_ELEM;
    }

    # Subtract @subt elements until they're all gone or $base[$bi] < 0
    1 while @subt and ($base[$bi] -= shift @subt) > 0;

    # Either @base element got negative, or we ran out of @subt elements
    if ($base[$bi] <= 0) {
        $carryover = abs($base[$bi]);
        say "\@base element #", $bi+1, " emptied. carry-over: $carryover. ",
            "Stayed with \@sub: @subt";
        $base[$bi] = 0;
    }
    elsif (not @subt) {  # we're done
        $base_idx = $bi;
        say "\@base element #", $bi+1, " emptied. carry-over: $carryover. ",
            "Stayed with ", scalar @subt, " \@subt elements";
        last BASE_ELEM;
    }
}
my $total_base_value = sum @base;

say "\nStayed with base: @base";

if (any { $_ > 0 } @base) {  # some base elements remained
    say "Stopped at \@base element index $base_idx (element number ",
        $base_idx+1, "), with value $base[$base_idx]";
}
else {
    if ($carryover) {
        say "Last carry-over: $carryover. Put it back at front of \@subt";
        unshift @subt, $carryover;
    }
    if (@subt) { say "Remained with \@subt elements: @subt" }
    else       { say "Used all \@subt to deplete all \@base" }
}

say "Total remaining: $total_base_value";
```

Prints

```
base: 10 15 6 2 (total: 33)
sub:  2 4 6 2 2 5 7 2 (total: 30)

@base element #1 emptied. carry-over: 2. Stayed with @sub: 2 2 5 7 2
@base element #2 emptied. carry-over: 3. Stayed with @sub: 2
@base element #3 emptied. carry-over: 3. Stayed with 0 @subt elements

Stayed with base: 0 0 1 2
Stopped at @base element index 2 (element number 3), with value 1
Total remaining: 3
```

(See end for version without diagnostic prints)

There are other possible cases, indicated by commented-out different `@subt` inputs

- that `@base` runs out while there are still non-zero `@subt` elements.  The simplest such case can be tested by using the next (commented-out) `@subt` input line; its additional elements keep nibbling away at `@base` values and deplete it altogether, with some `@subt` remaining
- that  all `@base` is driven to zero *and* `@subt` exactly runs out! This conspiracy can be effected with input such that `@base` and `@subt` add up to same (last commented-out `@subt` input)
- that some `@subt` elements are large enough to make a `@base` element so negative that there is enough of carry-over to deplete the next one, etc.  This is handled in the first `if` test, where we skip directly to the next `@base` element if there is still extra negative (to be carry-over), so that it can get used on it, etc

A note. A `@subt` element is always first removed from its front (by `shift`) and then subtracted from a `@base` element.  If that made that `@base` element negative, the negative value is used for carry-over and applied to the next `@base` element.

But, if that finally drove *the last `@base` element* into negative, the extra (negative) amount is considered to have stayed in that `@subt`'s element; it is put back at `@subt`'s front (`unshift`-ed).

Example: we had `5` (of some moneys, let's imagine) left in `@base`'s last element, and `@subt`'s element subtracted from it was `7`. Then that `@base`'s element is made into zero and that `@subt`'s element stays at `2`.

The code works with empty `@subt` as well.

---

Without extra prints in the loop, for easier reviewing

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 1.33 qw(sum any);  # 'any' was in List::MoreUtils pre-1.33

my @base = (10,15,6,2);
my @subt = (2,4,6,2,2,5,7,2);
# For testing other cases:
#my @subt = (2,4,6,2,2,5,7,2,5,5);  # @base runs out
#my @subt = (2,4,36,20);            # large @subt values, @base runs out
#my @subt = (2,4,21,2);             # large @subt values, @base remains
#my @subt = (2,4,6,2,2,5,7,2,3);    # @base runs out, @subt runs out
say "base: @base (total: ", sum(@base), ")";
say "sub:  @subt (total: ", sum (@subt), ")\n" if @subt;

my ($base_idx, $carryover) = (0, 0);

for my $bi (0..$#base) {
    $base[$bi] -= $carryover;

    # If still negative move to next @base element, to use carry-over on it
    if ($base[$bi] <= 0) {
        $carryover = abs($base[$bi]);
        $base[$bi] = 0;
        next;
    }

    # Subtract @subt elements until they're all gone or $base[$bi] < 0
    1 while @subt and ($base[$bi] -= shift @subt) > 0;

    # Either @base element got negative, or we ran out of @subt elements
    if ($base[$bi] <= 0) {
        $carryover = abs($base[$bi]);
        $base[$bi] = 0;
    }
    elsif (not @subt) {  # we're done
        $base_idx = $bi;
        last;
    }
}
my $total_base_value = sum @base;

say "Stayed with base: @base";

if (any { $_ > 0 } @base) {  # some base elements remained
    say "Stopped at \@base element index $base_idx (element number ",
        $base_idx+1, "), with value $base[$base_idx]";
}
else {
    unshift @subt, $carryover  if $carryover;

    if (@subt) { say "Remained with \@subt elements: @subt" }
    else      { say "Used all \@subt to deplete all \@base" }
}

say "Total remaining: $total_base_value";
```

Comment: I tried it with these data sets and it calculation was not correct (should be 3 but came up with 0). ```my @base = (10,15,6,2,20,20,5); 
my @sub = (-2,-4,-6,-2,-2,-5,-7,-2,-10,-10,-10,-5,-5,-3,-2); ``` I changed @sub to negative because my projects used negative but I did change this part of the code to add instead of subtract ```1 while @sub and ($base[$bi] += shift @sub) > 0;  ```. Let me know if I missed something. Thank you!!

Comment: @PaulYang Hm, funny -- good input, good catch, thank you.  looking into it...  (so that `@sub` you use can simply be considered with all positive numbers, `(2,4,6...)`, correct?)

Comment: @PaulYang Tthat `if ($base[$bi] < 0)` should be `if ($base[$bi] <= 0)`.  It had crossed my mind but then some distraction came along and I moved on, forgot about it (just got reminded).  That's one way how bugs happen.  The thing is, in this example at one point an element of `@base` is _exactly_ zeroed and the `$carryover` doesn't get adjusted (to zero) and I end up with excessive subtraction.  I tested, by my input didn't have such a case.  Fixed (with lots of debugging statements).  Let me check and then i'll adjust the post... (but you can try, make `<` into `<=`)

Comment: @PaulYang Updated the post, with `<` made into `<=` (also in code w/o extra prints at the end). Hopefully that's it (i'll test more).  Thank you

Comment: @PaulYang Note-- I assume that all input is strictly positive.  I wouldn't just change `-` into `+` in code as I'm not sure what may get tripped up elsewhere (by negative numbers). If you get negative, like in this example, one way to make it positive is `$_ = abs($_) for @sub;`

Comment: I will give it a test. Thank you for all your time and help.

Comment: I'm most interested in how the last element in ```@sub``` gets distributed, say for example if the last element of ```@sub``` was 10 and the last 2 element of ```@base``` was 5 (element $base[5]) and 6 (element $base[6]), I want it it to print that 5 out of the last ```@sub``` element of 10 was used in element $base[5] and the remaining 5 was used in element $base[5]. Once again thank you for all your help!!!!! If I could buy you dinner I would :)

Comment: @PaulYang Well, _that_ you actually have -- that's the `$carryover` in the first `if`: that's how much negative the `@base` element (that is getting subtracted from) got, so how much extra there was in the `@subt` element that was subtracted.  That is then subtracted from the next `@base` element. In your example, the `$carryover` in that first `if` would be `5`, and since the `@base` element was `5` you know how the `@subt` element of `10` got distributed -- `5` on the `@base` element on hand, and `5` carried over on the next `@base` element. (For some other details you may have to add code.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237372/discussion-between-paul-yang-and-zdim).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the expected values should be when you exhaust @base before exhausting @subtr. For the input you gave, it seems to work, though:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

my @base = (10, 15, 6, 2);
my @subtr = (2, 4, 6, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2);

my ($base_index, $subtr_index) = (0, 0);
my $subtracted = 0;

while ($base_index <= $#base) {
    while ($base[$base_index] - $subtracted > 0 && $subtr_index <= $#subtr) {
        say "Subtract at $subtr_index: $subtr[$subtr_index]";
        $subtracted += $subtr[$subtr_index++];
        say "Remains: ", $base[$base_index] - $subtracted;
    }
    last if $subtr_index > $#subtr;

    say "$base[$base_index] <= $subtracted";
    $subtracted -= $base[$base_index++];
    if ($base_index > $#base) {
        --$base_index;
        last
    }
    say "Carrying $subtracted to index $base_index ($base[$base_index])";
}
say "Finished at base index $base_index ($base[$base_index])";
say "Remaining value: ", $base[$base_index] - $subtracted;
my $remaining = $base[$base_index] - $subtracted;
$remaining += $_ for @base[$base_index + 1 .. $#base];
say "Remaining total: $remaining";
```

But I find working with copies of the arrays and removing their elements easier to understand:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

my @base = (10, 15, 6, 2);
my @subtr = (2, 4, 6, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2);

my @copy_base = @base;
my @copy_subtr = @subtr;

while (@copy_base && @copy_subtr) {
    if ($copy_base[0] > $copy_subtr[0]) {
        $copy_base[0] -= shift @copy_subtr;
    } else {
        my $first = shift @copy_base;
        $copy_base[0] += $first;
        if (1 == @copy_base && $copy_base[0] <= $copy_subtr[0]) {
            $copy_subtr[0] -= $copy_base[0];
            @copy_base = ();
        }
    }
    # say "b:@copy_base";
    # say "s:@copy_subtr";
    # say "";
}

if (@copy_base) {
    say "Ended at base index ", @base - @copy_base;
    say "Value left: ", $copy_base[0];

    my $total = 0;
    $total += $_ for @copy_base;
    say "Total: ", $total;
} else {
    say "Base exhausted";
}
if (@copy_subtr) {
    say "Ended at subtr index ", @subtr - @copy_subtr;
    my $remain = 0;
    $remain += $_ for @copy_subtr;
    say "$remain wasn't subtracted" if $remain;
} else {
    say "Subtr exhausted";
}
```

Comment: Sweet, yes that works perfectly!!! Thank you!

Comment: @PaulYang: Check the update.

Comment: Another edit, now it seems to work for all the possible results.

Comment: Ok I need add another list with 1 element for example ```@last_set = (1);``` How would I incorporated in so that once it exhaust @subtr it continues to @last_set and have it continue on where it left off?

Comment: Can't you just push @last_set to @subtr? Create a new question to ask a new question, you can always link to the preceding one for context.

Comment: OK yes, duh, I shouldve thought of that :)